# Changed html leads to problems with java code

Tags: java, html

I had programmed a web crawler and tried to use this part of code to get the input for my program:

```
String searchUrl = "https://www.ariva.de/aktiensuche/_result_table.m";
String searchBody = "page=0&page_size=25&sort=ariva_name&sort_d=asc&ariva_performance_1_year=_&ariva_performance_3_years=&ariva_performance_5_years=&index=0&founding_year=&land=0&industrial_sector=0&sector=0&currency=0&type_of_share=0&year=_all_years&sales=_&profit_loss=&sum_assets=&sum_liabilities=&number_of_shares=&earnings_per_share=&dividend_per_share=&turnover_per_share=&book_value_per_share=&cashflow_per_share=&balance_sheet_total_per_share=&number_of_employees=&turnover_per_employee=_&profit_per_employee=&kgv=_&kuv=_&kbv=_&dividend_yield=_&return_on_sales=_";

// post request to search URL
Document document = Jsoup.connect(searchUrl).requestBody(searchBody).post();

// find links in returned HTML
for(Element link:document.select("a[href]")) {
    System.out.println(link);
}
```

It should produce this:

```
<a href="/1-1_drillisch-aktie">1&amp;1 Drillisch</a>
<a href="/11_88_0_solutions-aktie">11 88 0 Solutions</a>
<a href="/1st_red-aktie">1st Red</a>
<a href="/21st-_cent-_fox_b_new-aktie">21ST. CENT. FOX B NEW</a>
<a href="/21st_century_fox-aktie">21st Century Fox</a>
<a href="/2g_energy-aktie">2G Energy</a>
<a href="/3i_group-aktie">3I Group</a>
<a href="/3i_infrastructure-aktie">3I INFRASTRUCTURE</a>
<a href="/3m_company-aktie">3M Company</a>
<a href="/3u_holding-aktie">3U Holding</a>
<a href="/3w_power-aktie">3W Power</a>
<a href="/4imprint_group-aktie">4imprint Group</a>
<a href="/4_sc-aktie">4 SC</a>
<a href="/XS0421565150">6,625% Statkraft AS 09/19 auf Festzins</a>
<a href="/7c_solarparken-aktie">7C Solarparken</a>
<a href="/888_holdings-aktie">888 Holdings</a>
<a href="/a-a-a-_aktiengesellschaft_allgemeine_anlageverwaltung-aktie">A.A.A. aktiengesellschaft allgemeine anlageverwaltung</a>
<a href="/a-g-_barr_______ls-04167-aktie">A.G. BARR LS-,04167</a>
<a href="/a-h-t-_syngas_technology-aktie">A.H.T. Syngas Technology</a>
<a href="/a-s-_creation_tapeten-aktie">A.S. Creation Tapeten</a>
<a href="/a-j_mucklow_group-1-aktie">A+J Mucklow Group</a>
<a href="/a-jmucklow_grp_pref-_ls_1-aktie">A+JMUCKLOW GRP PREF. LS 1</a>
<a href="/a2a-aktie">A2A</a>
<a href="/aac_technologies_holding-aktie">AAC Technologies Holding</a>
<a href="/aalberts-aktie">Aalberts</a>
```

Unfortunatelly, something changed in the html/url part and I am no expert in it. Can somebody help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to explain what behaviour you are seeing, and what the contents of the page which is returned is.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. the behavior is that nothing comes out at the moment. So there is no output.

Comment: You'll need to say what the contents of the page which is returned is.

Comment: Oh, I thought I did. The first part of the code is going to be used to produce the outcome which is the second part of the code. At the moment nothing is returned and I do not know why.

Comment: What is the status of the response? i.e. `document.connection().response().statusCode()`

Comment: It seems to be 0, if I used it right. As you may noticed I am a hobby developer and not a really good one. Sorry.